# Removing mold from walls without use of harmful chemicals

Tags: cleaning, home, kitchen, air

I have mold in the corner of my kitchen.

[image]

Usually remove it with mold-removing chemical products like bleach spray and it work perfectly. But recently some people told me these chemicals are harmful and I should not use them. It is very dangerous if you inhale the chemical while spraying. That is why I am asking you for an alternative non-toxic solution of this problem

Comment: I'm using Sodium hypochlorite (NaClO) based products for this. It is harmful to breath it and you must ventilate the room, but it is not so bad. After some time (few minutes), it changes to water and NaCl (table salt) so it is no longer harmful.

Comment: @j123b567 Sodium Hypochlorite *is* bleach.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Yes, it is *also* bleach. It kills mold perfectly and also make the wall white again so dual effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use white vinegar in a spray bottle.

Not only [can it kill 82% of mold species](http://blacktoxicmolds.com/vinegar-kill-mold.php), but it [is completely safe to use around children and pets.](http://greenopedia.com/sanitize-naturally/)

ALSO: note that breathing mold spores is dangerous as well. Mold spots should be cleaned regularly to prevent contamination of air and, since it is in your kitchen, food.

Comment: The big problem with vinegar is that it leaves behind nutrients for future mold. This may be no problem if you managed to radically change the conditions which made the mold grow in the first place (e.g., by removing that thermal bridge), but otherwise, mold will likely grow again.

Answer (score 11):

You can use hydrogen peroxide in a spray bottle to kill the mold and then just wipe it away.

It is probably worth noting that the mold that you can actually see is very likely the tip of the iceberg. If you can see mold growing on the wall it is pretty likely that there is mold inside of the wall as well.

It is also probably worth checking your roof/plumbing for leaks, molds usually need a pretty damp enviroment. If you can find the source of the water you may be able to solve the problem for good.

Answer (score 5):

The user Apaul34208 is correct. But since this is my job I must tell you that it is crucial to find the source of the mould. The source could be a pipe leak, roof leak or etc. There could be some serious problems behind the mould that need to be identified before the problem is resolved.

When it comes to just fixing mould problem none of those products cannot be harmful since you are not using it in the whole house or every day.

When and only when you find the source of the problem and **fix it** can you remove this using a reputable product, and when it dries you can apply acrylic based paint.

Comment: I forgot to write that I know why mold is there. It is because of condensing moisture. The ceiling of this room has no thermal isolation. Above it is the balcony of my neighbor. And in the winter the moisture from air is condensing in the corners, because the air is not moving much there. That is why I have to remove mold periodically and in the next summer I will put thermal isolation.

Comment: Yeah,thats the most usual reason...Thermal insulation is only permanent solution....Until then you can scrap wall paint completely , that should slow down this process

Answer (score 1):

When noticing mold, be sure to get into your attic + check for mold.

Use a flashlight or smell the air. If your attic smells musty, then you may have mold in your walls.

The easy way to get rid of mold in walls is to place one or more (depending on size of your home) industrial ozone generators in your attic + leave them running for a few days.

You can also do this inside your house too to get places that are difficult to reach with spray bottles, like between walls + built in furniture.

Works well.

In Austin, every few years we have a wet summer, where mold abounds. Whenever heat + moisture occur together, we flip on ozone generators all over the house now. We do this *before* mold occurs, to ensure no mold takes hold.

Answer (score 1):

A great way to help prevent the spreading of further mold is by purchasing a [dehumidifier](https://www.meacodehumidifiers.co.uk/). I had a very similar issue in my home and found that a dehumidifier helped mould, damp & condensation build-up by controlling the the moisture in the air, which prevents the mold from growing.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many DIY tips available on internet for mould removal. But let me tell you one thing, sometimes mould can be toxic. Some mould can produce spores that have mycotoxins that are very harmful if inhaled. So I would recommend you to hire a professional team who will help you remove mould safely.

Answer (score 0):

Clean Mold with Mixture:
1/2 Cup Water
1/2 Cup Vinegar
1 Teaspoon Tea Tree Oil

Cover Area with Tea Tree Oil(Prevention) and let air dry.

For hard spots use baking soda and tooth brush, in addition to the above recipe.

Answer (score 0):

White vinegar and water in a spray bottle can be applied to bathroom walls, shower stalls, and other flat surfaces. But you’ll be glad to know white vinegar is also effective at getting mold and mildew out. http://www.floodaz.com/how-to-kill-black-mold/

Answer (score 0):

- The root cause is damp, artificial drying will prevent re-occurance.
- Acid based food stuff such as vinegar, lemon juice etc. will kill it.
- Everything is chemicals, including the air you breath, the water you drink and every cell of your body.

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answers.