# Remove and prevent mildew from wallpaper

Tags: cleaning, bedroom

there has been "accident" in semi warm room, there was blankets and mattress against the wall, now there seems to be some mildew at wallpaper, because of the air could not flow thru, at least I think so.

I know there is some "removal" liquid to be used inside but I can't use it right now, its winter here, so what could be best way to do it and wait summer? Maybe after cleanup should properly let the air clean room (cold winter air) :)

Answer (score 3):

Mildew is developed due to a lack of ventilation and sun light exposure which develops this horrible moisture that clings to your belongings and especially your walls!
     First thing to remember is to open your windows every day if possible for at least an hour to circulate fresh air into the room and open the curtains/blinds too. Many of these modern windows have  a slider at the top to aid ventilation, otherwise I would suggest a small investment in a dehumidifier. 
E.g. 
    [ElectriQ MD280](http://www.appliancesdirect.co.uk/p/md280/amcor-md280-dehumidifier?refsource=APadwords&crtag=AP&gclid=CMW-neryzsoCFUEaGwodxs4KnA)

 
 As for treating the mildew already on the walls, you need to be a little more delicate with wallpaper, first off I'd suggest heating up or air conditioning the room to dry the affected areas then grab a sponge and washing-up liquid and wipe over. 
 
 Then use some chlorine bleach to rid any left over spores. Make sure you don't over-saturate the wallpaper as this could put air pockets in the wallpaper.
 
 If the mildew is really bad it may be worth calling an expert who can assess your home, treat the mildew and provide you with professional advice.
 Just remember to keep the room well ventilated and open a window if you have a group of people in the room.
 Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Once we can see mildew it unfortunately is too late to take precautions such as regular ventilating, heating, dehumidifying using an air conditioner (if available).

The fungal organisms and their spores will dwell deep within your wallpaper and possibly even underneath it. Superficially removing them, or treating them with chemicals will only lead to a very temporal relief. They will come back sooner or later.

We therefore have to **completely remove all of the affected wallpaper**. We may also have to remove the plastering, if affected. We will only find out after the wallpaper was removed.

Before we decorate the wall again we need to make sure all moisture is gone. This needs heating of the room and it needs frequent ventilation. To speed up the drying process there are special dehumidifying devices for rent (note that power consumption will be more expensive than the rental fees).

We then may treat the underground with a special anti-mildew preparation for disinfection before we mount our new wallpaper.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can do. If you can open the window for some time, you can use hydrogen peroxide in a spray or white vinegar. After that you have to take care of the humidity, you should reduce it or mold will appear again.

Some people use ozone generators to kill mold, but this is not a good idea if you live in this room, because ozone can be harmful for your lungs.

For more information you can check [this similar question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1961/removing-mold-from-walls-without-use-of-harmful-chemicals)

Comment: How long ozone will be harmful ? Hours, days ?

Comment: I am not sure if the room stays closed. But you can open the window for some time and let clean air come from outside after you stop the ozone generator.

Answer (score 0):

Mix a teaspoon of clove oil in a spray bottle of water. Spray the affected area and wipe dry. The clove oil will remove the mildew and help prevent it recurring.

Answer (score 0):

Use a sharp knife to scrape off any visible mildrew.

Then mix vinegar/water solution 1:1 and spray on the wall, or use something such as a strong bleach. This *will* bleach the wallpaper but it's already too late to save it anyway.